# My swap is getting full and I don't know what's happening

Tags: linux, swap, virtual-memory

[image]

```
    RANGE                                  SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE  BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x0000000087ffffff  2.1G online       yes   0-16
0x0000000100000000-0x0000000477ffffff 13.9G online       yes 32-142

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:      16G
Total offline memory:      0B
```

So I have 2 GB swap space but my system is only taking the first block? what's going wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. First tell us your operating system, then what kind of hardware (laptop, desktop, server, embedded, something else?) it is running on, then tell us what you are showing us; looks like the output of a command, what command? And what is the image from? Why do you say you have 2GB swap if the image only shows 128M? The more information you give us, the better we will be able to help you.

Comment: @terdon arch linux desktop i7 processor. Outputs are system monitor and lsmem. "Why do you say you have 2GB swap if the image only shows 128M?" That's exactly what I want to know.